# 'Hermes Debugger (RN)' is not supported by the selected device 'Android SDK built for x86' (Android)

Tags: react-native, flipper

I have a question. I'm working with react native in visual studio code and it's been a month since I started react-native. I have given the versions of the packages below

```
{
  "name": "Kurslarim",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "^0.73.18",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.73.1",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.73.2",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "^0.73.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}
```

When I used the "Open Debugger" option on the emulator, it did not open Chrome and asked me to install Flipper. I installed Flipper and installed the necessary dependencies. But now, when Flipper is opened, it gives the following error:

"Plugin 'Hermes Debugger (RN)' is unavailable
Device plugin 'Hermes Debugger (RN)' is not supported by the selected device 'Android SDK built for x86' (Android)"

I couldn't find many resources about this, and the ones I found didn't help me solve the problem. Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

I'm waiting to solve my problem